# Eclipse, Tomcat, spring framework application setup issue

Tags: mysql, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu, spring-mvc

I'm trying to setup a project on Eclipse, but it gives me these exception on the console and blank output inside the browser.

I wanted to contribute code to this project, and I have no clue how to get this to work. I did everything I was supposed to, but it won't work. I've checked the jdbc connection, the tomcat7 installation, the mysql installation. All of them seems to be working fine.

I was told that this project runs okay on a windows 7 box.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, MySql 5.5.24, Eclipse Juno, Tomcat 7

Please provide me with some information about the exceptions, or as to what I'm missing. Thank you.

> Oct 15, 2012 2:53:12 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:cmsadmin' did not
>   find a matching property. Oct 15, 2012 2:53:12 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:sites' did not find a
>   matching property. Oct 15, 2012 2:53:12 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Oct 15, 2012 2:53:12 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 858 ms Oct 15, 2012 2:53:12 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Oct 15, 2012 2:53:12 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 Oct 15, 2012 2:53:12 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO:
>   validateJarFile(/home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/sites/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class Oct 15, 2012 2:53:13 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing
>   Spring root WebApplicationContext log4j:WARN No appenders could be
>   found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Oct 15, 2012 2:53:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'groupService' defined in class path resource
>   [config/spring/spring-service-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'groupDao' while setting constructor argument; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'groupDao' defined in class path
>   resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' while setting bean
>   property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when
>   no Connection available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'groupDao' defined in class path resource
>   [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' while setting bean
>   property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when
>   no Connection available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>     ... 27 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when
>   no Connection available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>     ... 37 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available  at
>   org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:106)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:148)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
>     ... 44 more Oct 15, 2012 2:53:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error
>   listenerStart Oct 15, 2012 2:53:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [] startup failed due to previous errors Oct 15, 2012 2:53:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Closing Spring
>   root WebApplicationContext Oct 15, 2012 2:53:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
>   SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver
>   [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web
>   application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has
>   been forcibly unregistered. Oct 15, 2012 2:53:18 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO:
>   validateJarFile(/home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cmsadmin/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class Oct 15, 2012 2:53:18 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing
>   Spring root WebApplicationContext log4j:WARN No appenders could be
>   found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Oct 15, 2012 2:53:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'groupService' defined in class path resource
>   [config/spring/spring-service-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'groupDao' while setting constructor argument; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'groupDao' defined in class path
>   resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' while setting bean
>   property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when
>   no Connection available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'groupDao' defined in class path resource
>   [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' while setting bean
>   property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when
>   no Connection available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>     ... 27 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when
>   no Connection available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>     ... 37 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available  at
>   org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:106)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:148)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
>     ... 44 more Oct 15, 2012 2:53:22 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error
>   listenerStart Oct 15, 2012 2:53:22 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [/cms] startup failed due to previous errors Oct 15, 2012 2:53:22 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Closing Spring
>   root WebApplicationContext Oct 15, 2012 2:53:22 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
>   SEVERE: The web application [/cms] registered the JDBC driver
>   [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web
>   application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has
>   been forcibly unregistered. Oct 15, 2012 2:53:22 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory /home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/contento3/lib Oct 15, 2012 2:53:24 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory /home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/contento3/.git Oct 15, 2012 2:53:25 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory /home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/contento3/doc Oct 15, 2012 2:53:25 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory /home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/contento3/cmsadmin Oct 15, 2012 2:53:25 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory /home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/contento3/sites Oct 15, 2012 2:53:25 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory /home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/contento3/core Oct 15, 2012 2:53:26 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory /home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/contento3/DB Oct 15, 2012 2:53:26 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory /home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/contento3/host-manager Oct 15, 2012 2:53:26 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory /home/nuketro0p3r/Documents/Eclipse
>   Workspace/contento3/manager Oct 15, 2012 2:53:26 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Oct 15, 2012 2:53:26 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   13748 ms

Comment: Seems like classpath isnt assigned properly:(

Answer (score 0):

> Oct 15, 2012 2:53:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:cmsadmin' did not find a matching property.

Eclipse adds a "source" attribute to your  element in server.xml. Never mind that  should not be in server.xml... that property is not recognized by Tomcat so you get a WARNING.

> Oct 15, 2012 2:53:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupService' defined in class path resource [config/spring/spring-service-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'groupDao' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupDao' defined in class path resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cmsSecuritySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [config/spring/spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available at [...]

So, obviously that's a Spring/Hibernate problem. I suspect there are other errors that you haven't posted, here... maybe something like your JDBC driver can't be loaded or something. Or, maybe you really don't have `hibernate.dialect` set and therefore Hibernate can't properly configure itself.